# Is Visual Studio only used for programming?

Tags: visual-studio

Is Visual Studio only used for programming and coding, or does it have other features?

In a work environment, how is Visual Studio used for other kinds of work?

Comment: I think there might still be too many 'is' in the title.

Comment: How about you go read the product page on the microsoft web site.

Comment: One wonders whether the question is automatically "not programming related"? I'd love to be able to cast a *single* close vote on it, but I can't (it would be binding) - so consider this a virtual vote to close ;-p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do some things outside of coding, but it's not really the best at many of those.  You can edit text files, xml files, use it to access a database and do queries, make diagrams (class diagrams) from your code, analyze code, test your applications, debug applications that have crashed.  There's also some sort of community element to the start page, but I've never really gotten into that.  I think I have an least 1 instance of devenv up 99% of the time, but then again, I write a lot of code. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the better question is why are you trying to find usages for Visual Studio other than coding? It's like asking what else can you do with a web browser other than surf the net.

Comment: Oh I hope that answer is really just a clever stab at the current direction of the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only non-coding related feature it could possibly have, is that you can use it as a plain old text editor.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally only used for coding or changing XML files. It is also able to connect to  SQL Databases